# Usb hid device insert/removal detection winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, hid

I have created winapi application witch uses other .exe via createprocess to get/set reports. And now I need some kind of way to detect that this USB HID device was plugged/unplugged from computer when application is running. Hardest part of it is that in that app I know just VID and PID and I don't have any handles to that USB HID device. is there any way to solve this problem or I first need handle of the device?

Edit

If anyone is interested why I need it. I want to disable/enable controls of my app when i plug and unplug device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at first you **must** register own window for receive [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx) message with [`DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363205(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363208(v=vs.85).aspx) for [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545972(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx) - windows will be not send this notification without registration!

```
case WM_CREATE:

    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter = { 
        sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE), 
        DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE,
        0,
        GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE
    };

    if (!(_Handle = RegisterDeviceNotification(hwnd, &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE)))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    break;
```

and unregister on destroy:

```
case WM_DESTROY:
    if (_Handle) UnregisterDeviceNotification(_Handle);
    break;
```

after this you will be receive notification. if

> I know just VID and PID

you can search for `L"#VID_????&PID_????#"` in `dbcc_name` (where in place ? your actual `vid` and `pid`values)

```
case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
    case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
        {
            PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE p = (PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)lParam;
            if (p->dbcc_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE &&
                p->dbcc_classguid == GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE)
            {
                DbgPrint("%S\n", p->dbcc_name);
                if (wcsstr(p->dbcc_name, L"#VID_****&PID_****#"))
                {

                    DbgPrint("%s\n", wParam == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL ? "arrival" : "removal");
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: `_Handle` is a reserved symbol in C and C++, and you should not be using it. If you do you'll risk colliding with symbols defined by the language implementation. It's their namespace after all.

Comment: @IInspectable "`_Handle` is a reserved symbol in C and C++" - hmm, first time listen about this keyword. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9.aspx) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) it not listed. and main - if I will be use reserved language keyword - compiler give me error (or warning how minimum) but `CL` `19.00.24210` not give me this warning. (I use `_Handle` as window class member if so) - and this is all "errors" which you found here ? nothing more ?

Comment: A *reserved symbol* and a *keyword* are different things. A compiler won't issue an error or warning when using a reserved symbol. This is something you need to know about [identifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers).

Comment: @IInspectable - and where `_Handle` is exactly marked as reserved ? and maximum what be if this happens - compiler error - and `ctrl+h` for replace `_Handle` for say `_hNotification`

Comment: From the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) I posted in my previous comment: *"[I]dentifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved"*. Take your time to work through the document. You might even learn a thing or two. Then again, you're not a big fan of contracts anyway, so you might as well skip it.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter. I really didn't need to have arrival and removal maseges. WM_DEVICECHANGE was enough. Although when i connect or  diconnect device I get WM_DEVICECHANGE message 3 times.

Comment: @andrius - `I get WM_DEVICECHANGE message 3 times` - what more concrete messages ? I mean `wParam` (`DBT_*`) . `I really didn't need to have arrival and removal maseges` - but how you want have notify about insert/removal if `didn't need to have arrival and removal maseges` ?

Comment: @RbMm I don't know how to properly explain, but WM_DEVICECHANGE fires when I plugg or unplugged devices. Then i just refresh all my controls and it is good for me for now. I checked with debugger and I saw that when I insert or remove usb device. case WM_DEVICECHANGE: fires 3 times. wParam = 7.

Comment: @andrius 7 this is `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED`, if you want *exactly* know when your (but not any) device is pluged/unpluged - you need do as i wrote - `RegisterDeviceNotification` and look for `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` and `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` with your `"#VID_****&PID_****"` in name - are you try do this ?

Comment: @RbMm I have been trying to do this but GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE gave me error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE.

Comment: @andrius - `#include <initguid.h>
#include <usbiodef.h>`

Answer (score 3):

Windows sends to all top-level windows the [WM_DEVICECHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx) message when new devices or media becomes availables. Checks for the event [DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa363205(v=vs.85).aspx) in `wParam`. With the event `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` lParam can be converted to a [DEV_BROADCAST_HDR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa363246(v=vs.85).aspx)  structure.
When this is done, you check `dbch_devicetype` from `DEV_BROADCAST_HDR`, and convert `lParam` again to [DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa363245(v=vs.85).aspx), or [DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa363249(v=vs.85).aspx) if `dbch_devicetype` is equal to `DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE`or `DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME`, I'm not sure to remember which one.

Comment: at first you not got notify for usb device without  `RegisterDeviceNotification` with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE`, at second we need `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` here